# How to order posts tag by tag?

Tags: wp-query, loop, filters, tags, order

I want to order my posts by tags with only one WP_Query()

In my WP_Query I would like to display
2 posts with tags `portrait`

2 posts with tags `paysage`

2 posts with tags `portrait`

2 posts with tags `paysage`

2 posts with tags `portrait`

2 posts with tags `paysage`

Etc...

And I need to order these posts by recents.

What is the query to do that ?

Thanks

PS : Sorry I cannot use code because I'm with my iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Like Eugene mentioned in his answer you need to run a query for each tag.  I would create a foreach loop that went through each tag then queried the latest 2 posts from each.

```
$tags = get_tags();
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {

    echo '<h3>' .$tag->name. '</h3>';
    $tag_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                              'tag_id' => $tag->term_id,
                              'posts_per_page' => 2,
                              'no_found_rows' => true,
                               ) );
        while ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) : $tag_query->the_post();
        // Do stuff
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, you suggest to create two queries. One for tag `portrait` and tag `paysage`. But what about the pagination. The only reason why I want to use only one query is the pagination. With two queries i'll get two paginations on my page.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do with one query, even from database point of view (without unions).

I would recommend you to use separate queries for each term. Don't invent a wheal, don't over complicate your code.